# Why can't I calculate the square root of a "long"? (infant programmer)

Tags: java, long-integer, square-root

Alright, so I just started learning Java two days ago. I am using Java SE and Netbeans 8.0.2, and I have written a few exceptionally basic applications. However, I'm trying to find the square root of a 32-64 bit number (a "long"), and I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Root {
    public static void main(String[] arguements) {
        long number;
        number = 2500000000;
        System.out.println("The square root of "
              + number
              + " is "
              + Math.sqrt(number)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include any errors you get as part of your question.

Comment: That being said, you're getting an error because `2500000000` isn't a long, it's an out-of-range int. `2500000000L` is a long.

Comment: also if you have tips or can point out resources that would've helped me figure this out on my own. that would also be appreciated

Comment: First resource: Google.  If @azurefrog is correct, then you're far from the first to have this problem.

Comment: Sorry, the error says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at com.java24hours.Root.main(Root.java:6)"

Comment: I thought a long was just a integer larger than 32 bits?

Comment: @EliAbood That runtime error means your code didn't compile correctly, and your IDE should have indicated such.  Always make sure you have clean code before you try to run it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem is that `Math.sqrt` accepts only double parameters. The solution is simply to cast from long to double.

```
Math.sqrt((double)number);
```

As well as that, a long formally ends with the suffix l or L. That was not added to your long variable, so that could contribute to the problem.

Comment: this line `number = 2500000000;` is the cause of the problem, so I'd suggest mentioning that to OP. Also, you need not cast from `long` to `double`. this is done without the need of explicit cast.

Comment: Yep thanks! It was the lack of an L. Sorry for the dumb question, I'm teaching myself and I didn't realize it needed a prefix.

Comment: No problem! I have quick problems like that all the time as well, and I've been doing java for a couple months now. Enjoy coding java :P